# Mavericks or El Captain for old MacBook Pro (early'11)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, upgrade

In case of performance for multithreaded applications, development (Java) and virtualization (Parallels 11), what's better - upgrading to 10.9 Mavericks or El Captain? (or Yosemite) ?

Now I'm on 10.8.5, MacBook Pro 15", i7-2.0x4, on SSD with 16GB RAM

P.S. upgrading needed as Parallels 11 doesn't support 10.8

Comment: You'd be better off upgrading to the newest system. You would be getting the newest tools, and would have access to the newest items, making future upgrades a much greater span of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go El Cap. The marginal performance decrease (especially on your machine) is near zero compared to 10.9. You'll get better support, newer features, newer apps, etc.

Comment: where is the main performance degradation of El Cap then - in OpenGL apps (games, video etc.) ? I was also looking other discusstions about it.

Comment: @yetanothercoder Huh, I haven't seen any threads about that. Can you link the thread you're referring to?

Comment: I've seen some concerning fps degradation, ex: http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/16070567139

Comment: @yetanothercoder Interesting, I don't know anything about that–I haven't experienced any degradation personally.